# CARemoteLayer*/IOSurfaceRef + NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plugins, calayer, nsview

I'm building a view-based plugin architecture where I have a separate process for plugins and want to assign each plugin an `NSView`. I've looked into `CARemoteLayerServer/Client` and `IOSurfaceRef` usage, but both of them only allow a single drawing view. A plugin's view may have many subviews, and can receive events like it were part of the main application. Any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to interact with an `NSView` directly across process boundaries. That said, `CARemoteLayerServer` supports a layer tree, not just a single layer. This means that your UI would most certainly need to be constructed using layers, but `NSView` can still be useful when it comes to the event handling aspects.

Both the client and the server can contain the shared remote layer inside their own `NSViews` because you can create a layer-hosting `NSView` and assign the shared layer to it. The `NSView` can then intercept mouse and keyboard events which could be passed to the other process over the XPC connection for its own `NSView` (which contains the shared layer) to interpret. I'm not entirely sure how fast this would be as I haven't experimented with it myself, but I would assume that it would be almost as instantaneous as interacting with a normal view.

If you're interested in playing around more with remote layers, there's a nice [example project](https://github.com/krevis/RemoteLayerDemo) along with an accompanying SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293409/can-caremotelayerserver-and-caremotelayerclient-be-used-between-processes) that you could check out